# Traversing a pre-defined path with a delay in SFML - C++

Tags: c++, path-finding, sfml

I want the player to move smoothly & slowly through a vector of co-ordinates that define a path, below is an illustration of what i mean.

```
[P][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[.][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[.][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[.][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[.][.][E][ ][ ]
```

Once the path has been found the player should move between each tile with a visual delay, i have tried to code this behavior in a variety of ways but it seems that this a problem created by running Update/Render on the same thread, i think?

Here is what i tried

```
 if (pathFound)
 {     
    for (auto path : waypoint_queue)
    {
        Move(this->character.getPosition(), path)
    }
    waypoint_queue.clear();
    pathFound = false;
} else {  }
```

Running this without a delay in an attempt to lerp between the co-ordinates of each "Next Tile" essentially teleports the player to the final node.

Running this with a delay of 1s for 10 tiles halts the program for 10 seconds then teleports the player to the final node.

How do i go about producing C#-like co-routine behavior that can update variables with a timed delay whilst also rendering them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So [@tkausl's](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/49789/tkausl) answer worked, the player now moves smoothly along the predefined path, here is the updated code:

Edit: Bonus [WebM](http://webmshare.com/play/9W834) of it working

```
if (pathFound)
{
    // A path has been found
    const float unitsPerTick = 8; // Speed in Units per tick
    auto waypoint = waypoint_queue.front(); // The waypoint in use

    Vector2i movementVector = Vector2i(waypoint.x - this->character.getPosition().x,
        waypoint.y - this->character.getPosition().y);

    float moveVecLength = sqrt((movementVector.x * movementVector.x) + (movementVector.y * movementVector.y));

    if (moveVecLength < 0.2)
    {
        /// Move the player by the movement vector
        this->character.setPosition(this->character.getPosition().x + movementVector.x, this->character.getPosition().y + movementVector.y);    
        waypoint_queue.pop_front();
    }
    else {
        /// Normalize the movement vector           
        movementVector.x = movementVector.x / moveVecLength;
        movementVector.y = movementVector.y / moveVecLength;

        /// Scale the movement vector by the units per tick
        movementVector = Vector2i(movementVector.x * unitsPerTick, movementVector.y * unitsPerTick);

        /// Move the character by the new movement vector
        this->character.setPosition(this->character.getPosition().x + movementVector.x, this->character.getPosition().y + movementVector.y);
    }

    if (waypoint_queue.empty())
        pathFound = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, you're applying **all** waypoints in the same frame, which makes the character appear at the last waypoint directly, without moving at all. What you have to do is take on waypoint per frame and move only this one step. Or, better yet, move **a bit** in direction of the first waypoint, then, if you're near enough, discard the first waypoint.

Pseudo-Code:

```
 if (pathFound)
 {  
    const float unitsPerTick = 0.2; //Speed in Units per Tick   
    auto waypoint = waypoint_queue->front();
    auto movevec = waypoint->getPosition() - this->character.getPosition();
    if (movevec->getLength() < unitsPerTick ) {
         this->character.move(movevec);
         waypoint_queue->pop();
    } else {
        movevec->normalize()->scale(unitsPerTick);
        this->character.move(movevec);
    }

    if(waypoint_queue->empty())
        pathFound = false;
} else {  }
```

Something like this should do what you want.

---

Edit: Since SMFL's vector class has no such methods here an example how to do the calculations yourself.

Scale a vector `somevector` by `x`

```
somevector *= x;
```

Length of a vector:

```
float length = sqrt(somevector.x * somevector.x + somevector.y * somevector.y);
```

Normalize a vector:

```
somevector /= length; //For length, see above
```

Comment: I think i understand my problem now, so i should be moving the player on each Update a little bit closer to the "current target" until I'm within a reasonable degree of accuracy then set the next "current target" to the next tile along. 

However i'm a bit stumped with some of the math functions, the Vector2i class in SFML doesn't come with normalize()/scale()/getLength() functions, could you explain a little what they do? - thanks

Comment: See my edit. Also, you should use Vector2**f** instead of **i** because integers aren't precise enough

Comment: Edited once again, i just noticed, the classes provide math-operations with scalars.